# Why is the date_format() returning wrong week in Pyspark?

Tags: date, debugging, pyspark, week-number

Was trying to get week of the month, from a date column in a pyspark dataframe ? I am using the following schematic to get week:`date_format(to_date("my_date_col","yyyy-MM-dd") "W")` from [https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/get-week-number-from-date-in-pyspark/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20get%20Week,we%20use%20weekofmonth()%20function.](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/get-week-number-from-date-in-pyspark/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20get%20Week,we%20use%20weekofmonth()%20function.)

Oddly this seems to work for every week, except for 1st week of August 20!

```
base.filter(col("acct_cycle_cut_dt").between("2020-08-01","2020-08-07")\
       ).select("acct_cycle_cut_dt",month("acct_cycle_cut_dt"),\
                date_format(to_date("acct_cycle_cut_dt","yyyy-MM-dd"), "W")\
              ).limit(4).show()

+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|acct_cycle_cut_dt|month(acct_cycle_cut_dt)|date_format(to_date(`acct_cycle_cut_dt`, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), W)|
+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|       2020-08-02|                       8|                                                         2|
|       2020-08-07|                       8|                                                         2|
|       2020-08-07|                       8|                                                         2|
|       2020-08-07|                       8|                                                         2|
+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

base.filter(col("acct_cycle_cut_dt").between("2020-07-01","2020-07-07")\
       ).select("acct_cycle_cut_dt",month("acct_cycle_cut_dt"),\
                date_format(to_date("acct_cycle_cut_dt","yyyy-MM-dd"), "W")\
              ).limit(4).show()

+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|acct_cycle_cut_dt|month(acct_cycle_cut_dt)|date_format(to_date(`acct_cycle_cut_dt`, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), W)|
+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|       2020-07-03|                       7|                                                         1|
|       2020-07-03|                       7|                                                         1|
|       2020-07-02|                       7|                                                         1|
|       2020-07-02|                       7|                                                         1|
+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your code and data is hard to read and there is no result for '2020-08-01' and executed result, reproducible data.

Comment: Pardon me for the bad editing !

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct result, it is not wrong.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('date', to_timestamp('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd')) \
  .withColumn('month', month('date')) \
  .withColumn('week', date_format('date', 'W')) \
  .show(10, False)

+-------------------+-----+----+
|date               |month|week|
+-------------------+-----+----+
|2020-08-01 00:00:00|8    |1   |
|2020-08-02 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-03 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-04 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-05 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-06 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-07 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-08 00:00:00|8    |2   |
|2020-08-09 00:00:00|8    |3   |
|2020-08-10 00:00:00|8    |3   |
+-------------------+-----+----+
```

You can even check this from the calendar,

[image]

where the 1st of August is really in the first week of August and the 2nd of Auguet is in the second week.

Comment: That makes sense, Silly me completely overlooked this, Much Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In August , month is starting from Saturday. When you have date as "2020-08-02" or "2020-08-07" both the dates have only one Sunday before in the month. Your script will always return incorrect result whenever there is a month start before or on weekend.